# My bcp hangs after creating an empty file

Tags: sql, xml, bcp

I am trying to drop a file into a directory on the local machine (same machine running SQL Instance).  The content of the table I am trying to drop out is in xml format.

ie.  table=xmlOutFiles, fieldName = xmlContent;  fieldName contains essentially varchar(max) data that is to become the xml file we need.

When the bcp command is executed it seems to create the file in the @dest location, size = 0 bytes and then the process running from within SMSS just sits there waiting for something!

I cannot do anything with that empty file, like delete it, unless I use task manager to kill the process "bcp.exe".

I have tried multiple combinations of the bcp flags, etc.

Running the bcp command from a system prompt, replacing the "@vars" seems to work but I really need it to be part of my SQL Trigger script and function.

Assistance appreciated!!!!

```
Select @dest = (Select filename from xmlOutfiles)
Select @cmd = 'bcp "Select xmlContent from ProcureToPay.dbo.XmlOutFiles" queryout '+@dest+' -x -w -T -S' + @@servername

Exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

I have tried executing with -T and -Uusername -Ppassword parameters, etc.

This command works from the DOS prompt:

```
bcp "Select xmlContent from Procure.To.Pay.dbo.XmlOutFiles" queryout c:\temp\test.xml -x -w -T S<myservernameHere>
```